# qTranslate X and AJAX: language switch does not detect ajax-loaded URLs

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a [WordPress theme loading pages via AJAX](http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/bridge38/), and require these pages to be both in English and German. I always use [qTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) for these cases, as I can quickly and manually populate the content in my languages of choice.

However, qTranslate X does not read the AJAX-updated URLs. **Consider this example:** User is on a given post (*website.com/firstpost*) reading on German, as it is the default language. The user clicks on another post, going to *website.com/anotherpost*. Being there, the user wants to read this "another post" in English, so the user clicks the English flag. Because *website.com/anotherpost* was loaded via AJAX, qTranslate X takes the user to *website.com/en/firstpost* (or eg. *website.com/firstpost?lang=en*), as for the plugin, the URL is still *website.com/firstpost*.

I am hoping someone has experience with this specific plugin and it running with AJAX calls. I am very new to AJAX, as I have never worked with it, so pardon for any stupid terms and/or thought-processes on my behalf.

If you require more information, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the current language through the ajax call:

```js
var actioncall = {
  action: 'myajax_function',
  qtx_lang : MyAjax.qtx_lang
};

$.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl,actioncall , function(response) {

// do stuff 

}, 'json');
});
```

to get that, you need to:

```
global $q_config;
wp_localize_script( 'existing_script', 'MyAjax', 
     array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'qtx_lang' => $q_config['language']
 ) );
```

then finally:

on your prefix_ajax_myajax_function(), that fetches the posts, you can use it like this:

```php
$qtx_lang= $_POST['qtx_lang'];
....
$title = qtranxf_use($qtx_lang,$the_page->post_title);
```